# What does implodeQuery mean?

Tags: php, javascript, ajax, facebook

I was checking the source page of facebook . I found a function which frequently used there .
the line was

```
input_len=URI.implodeQuery(this.data).length
```

I cant understand what the line means and what `implodeQuery`  .

I also need th same function for php .

Please help me ! thanks

Comment: Have you tried googling for docs?

Comment: It probably grabs an object and compiles all of it's keys and values into a query string like "a=apple&b=bee&c=carrot".

Comment: @Lucanos but what is that `this.data` ? it should be this.data.{something} .

Comment: @Ash: I am assuming it is an object, so, using my example above, the object would have elements like `this.data.a="apple"`, `this.data.b="bee"` and `this.data.c="carrot"`. If in doubt, get Firebug (or similar) and insert `console.log(this.data);` into your javascript to see exactly what you are dealing with.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`URI.implodeQuery` appears to serialize the passed object into a query string (for something like a `GET` request).  This functions much like [jQuery.param()](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.param/).

From the JavaScript console on Facebook:

```
> URI.implodeQuery({'greeting':'hello','number':2,'vegetable':'carrot'});
"greeting=hello&number=2&vegetable=carrot"
```

Answer (score 0):

URI.implodeQuery() is not native to javascript.

It's a method defined somewhere else in the Facebook code.

Comment: i cant find function imploQuery in that page or javascript linked to that page.